# Google App script run one function finished and then other one

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a sheet with bigquery connector and then send email of the sheet.
By using record macros I have a auto refresh function but I want to run the auto refesh function and then send out email. However it always run auto refresh first and while query is running, the second function of sending email is done, which I won't the refresh data in the email.
I used the `SpreadsheetApp.flush();`  in between but it didn't work.
Any one can help?

```
function Auto() {
  AutoRefresh();
  SendEmail();
};


function AutoRefresh() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}

function SendEmail() { 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var message = {
  to: "xxx@abc.com",
  subject: "test email",
  body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find the report attached.\n\nThank you",
  name: "test report",
  attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Report Test")]
}
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}
```

Comment: You probably want [waitForCompletion](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `refreshData()` is asynchronous . In other words, Google Apps Script is not able to know when it have fisnished.

Workaround.

Instead of `SpeadsheetApp.flush()` use `Utilities.sleep(millisenconds)`

```
function Auto() {
  AutoRefresh();
  Utilities.sleep(60000) // Sleep 1 minute.
  SendEmail();
};
```